# Erro ao Fazer Backup Banco de dados Windows Forms

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms, windows

Galera to com dificuldades em resolver esse problema! 
Minha aplicação é em Windows Forms. Eu preciso realizar Backup dos dados atraves da propria aplicação, Mas quando eu executo para realizar ele me informa esse erro.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obs: Meu backup é em um servidor na rede não local

Esse é meu código para realizar o backup.

```
 try
        {
            Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
            timer2.Enabled = true;
            if ((!System.IO.Directory.Exists(@"C:\\DBBackup")))
            {
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\\DBBackup");
            }
            string destdir = "C:\\DBBackup\\SISTEMA_CCA " + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy_HH-mm-ss") + ".bak";
            cg.con = new SqlConnection(cn.DBconn);
            cg.con.Open();
            string cb = "backup database SISTEMA_CCA to disk='" + destdir + "'with init,stats=10";
            cg.cmd = new SqlCommand(cb);
            cg.cmd.Connection = cg.con;
            cg.cmd.ExecuteReader();
            cg.con.Close();
            st1 = LB_Usuario.Text;
            st2 = "Backup realizado com sucesso";
            cf.LogFunc(st1, System.DateTime.Now, st2);
            MessageBox.Show("Operação concluída com sucesso", "Backup - Banco de dados", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Erro ao Fazer o Backup", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
```

Desde de já agradeço!

Answer (score 4):

A mensagem é clara, não pode achar o arquivo de backup.

Não se esqueça que ao executar o comando `backup database` no servidor do `SQL-Server`, ele vai procurar *"C:\DBBackup"* no disco local do servidor. Se o arquivo estiver no `C:` da máquina que estiver executado o aplicativo não vai encontrar o arquivo.

Comment: Obrigado Ricardo Pontual. foi um erro meu em não observar esse detalhe. obrigado deu certo!

Comment: tranquilo, estamos aqui pra ajudar :)

Answer (score 0):

Tenha em conta alguns pontos:

1. O endereço indicado no comando de backup é sempre considerando como partida a visão a partir do servidor onde está instalada a instância
2. O utilizador configurado no Services.msc do SQL Server deve ser um utilizador que tenha acesso comprovado ao endereço indicado. Costuma-se sempre aconselhar a usar o SYSTEM (quando backup é feito localmente) ou um utilizador de domínio caso o backup seja realizado em local remoto (lembrar de configurar os acessos da pasta)

Pelo que vejo no seu código, está a criar uma pasta sim, mas está a criar na máquina onde está a correr o software, e não no servidor do SQL Server. Claro, isso considerando que o servidor de BD e o software estão a correr em máquinas separadas. Caso estejam a correr na mesma máquina, é suposto que o código funcione (mas reveja os pontos 1 e 2)